# count co-occurrence neighbors in a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector : for example S=(0,3,2,0,1,2,0,1,1,2,3,3,0,1,2,3,0).
I want to count co-occurrence neighbors, for example the first neighbor "o,3" how many times did it happen till the end of the sequence? Then it investigates the next pair"2,0" and similarly do it for other pairs.
Below is a part of my code:

```
s=size(pic);
S=s(1)*s(2);
V = reshape(pic,1,S);
min= min(V);
Z=zeros(1,S+1);
Z(1)=min;
Z(2:end)=V;
for i=[0:2:length(Z)-1];
contj=0
    for j=0;length(Z)-1;

        if  Z(i,i+1)= Z(j,j+1) 
            contj=contj+1

        end 

    end
    count(i)= contj
end
```

It gives me this error:

```
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment
```

in this line:

```
if  Z(i,i+1)= Z(j,j+1)
```

I read similar questions and apply the tips on it but they didn't work!

Comment: In `S = [0,3,2,0,...]`, does (3,2) also count as a pair? Or only (0,3) and (2,0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pairs are defined *without overlapping* (according to comments):

```
S = [0,3,2,0,1,2,0,1,1,2,3,3,0,1,2,3]; %// define data
S2 = reshape(S,2,[]).'; %'// arrange in pairs: one pair in each row
[~, jj, kk] = unique(S2,'rows'); %// get unique labels for pairs
pairs = S2(jj,:); %// unique pairs
counts = accumarray(kk, 1); %// count of each pair. Or use histc(kk, 1:max(kk))
```

Example: with `S` as above (I introduce blanks to make pairs stand out),

```
S = [0,3, 2,0, 1,2, 0,1, 1,2, 3,3, 0,1, 2,3];
```

the result is

```
pairs =
     0     1
     0     3
     1     2
     2     0
     2     3
     3     3

counts =
     2
     1
     2
     1
     1
     1
```

---

If pairs are *defined* without overlapping but *counted* with overlapping:

```
S = [0,3,2,0,1,2,0,1,1,2,3,3,0,1,2,3]; %// define data
S2 = reshape(S,2,[]).'; %'// arrange in pairs: one pair in each row
[~, jj] = unique(S2,'rows'); %// get unique labels for pairs
pairs = S2(jj,:); %// unique pairs
P = [S(1:end-1).' S(2:end).']; %// all pairs, with overlapping
counts = sum(pdist2(P,pairs,'hamming')==0);
```

If you don't have `pdist2` (Statistics Toolbox), replace last line by

```
counts = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, pairs.', permute(P, [2 3 1]))), 3);
```

Result:

```
>> pairs
pairs =
     0     1
     0     3
     1     2
     2     0
     2     3
     3     3
>> counts
counts =
     3     1     3     2     2     1
```

Comment: Luis,                                                                    I used your codes but it gives this error:                            ' Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.  ' in this line :                                                '  [~, jj, kk] = unique(S2,'rows');  '  .                           Is it because i used reshape in advance for converting matrix to a vector?                                                           Can you again help me? thanks.

Comment: @pic Have you tried my code exactly as it is? It works in the provided example

Comment: If you use an old Matlab version, try changing that line to `[ii, jj, kk] = unique(S2,'rows');`

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer, but there is still a problem. The pairs those you took are right but in counting stage the consequence should be this :   ' (0,1):3, (0,3):1, (1,2):3, (2,0):2, (2,3):2, (3,3):1' . For example the pair (0,1) if you scan it in sequence there are 3 pairs of it.

Comment: Excuse me I use version 7.6 of matlab and it doesn't have pdist2 , is there any equal code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do it using `sparse` command

```
os = - min(S) + 1; % convert S into indices 
% if you want all pairs, i.e., for S = (2,0,1) count (2,0) AND (0,1):
S = sparse( S(1:end-1) + os, S(2:end) + os, 1 );
% if you don't want all pairs, i.e., for S = (2,0,1,3) count (2,0) and (1,3) ONLY:
S = sparse( S(1:2:end)+os, S(2:2:end) + os, 1 );
[f s c] = find(S);
f = f - os; % convert back
s = s - os;
```

co-occurences and their count are in the pairs `(f,s) - c`

```
>> [f s c]
ans =

 2     0     2  % i.e. the pair (2,0) appears twice in S...
 3     0     2
 0     1     3
 1     1     1
 1     2     3
 3     2     1
 0     3     1
 2     3     2
 3     3     1
```

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand. What is S?  is it in continuation of my codes? and i want the second condition you mentioned, i mean "S = (2,0,1,3) count (2,0) and (1,3) ONLY"  May you please explain more?